# Best way to store data retrieved from JSON file?

Tags: json, excel, store

I'm hoping to store data I get from a server which sends data via JSON.  I don't want anything fancy - just would like to save the data so I can play with it in excel.

Here is the JSON URL:  http://realm3.castle.wonderhill.com/api/map.json

I'm extremely surprised there are no solutions out there on this yet.

What would you guys used to achieve this?

Comment: Store it in what? Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the json into a text file formatted as CSV - Excel can read that.  I'll come up with some sample code in PHP after dinner.

EDIT: Bah, dinner can wait.

```
<?php

// Download data to a string
$mapData = file_get_contents('http://realm3.castle.wonderhill.com/api/map.json');

// Convert JSON into an Array
$mapData = json_decode($mapData);

var_dump($mapData);
echo "\n";
```

Saved the above into `test.php` and then ran it like this:

`php test.php | less`

and the output is a huge data structure.  You'll need to extract what you want and then use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write the content to a file that you'll then read into Excel.  The output doesn't seem to have any special characters, but if you do have a problem make sure to encode the data as CP1252 so Excel for Windows can read it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  You'll have to forgive me, but what am I using to save and run this code?  I'm afraid I am just learning and don't have the know-how I desperately want/need.